# Why does apt install, install an older version of Redis?

Tags: apt, redis

I am learning Ubuntu and I am installing Redis. When I use the following guide, an older version of Redis is installed. 4.0.x

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04

According to redis.io, the latest stable version is 5.0.5. Why does `apt install` install a 4.0.x version and not the latest 5.0.5 version?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us what release you are using, so https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=redis is probably the best we can provide for what you've provided.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I would add `apt-cache policy redis` to your question, particularly if it's something different to the output of the packages link I've already provided (ie. if it's an older packages than you should get, you have a problem in sources and the apt-cache policy would provide clues such as a bad/out-dated mirror that you should change etc)

Comment: 5.0.4 is in Ubuntu 19.04. 5.0.5 is in testing for Ubuntu 19.10.